# linking android applications

Tags: android, android-intent

- [Linking to Your Products](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html)
- [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

In **application A** I call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("testapp://details?id=testid"));
startActivity(intent);
```

In **application B** I declare:

```
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="testapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I get: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=....`

How should be declared the Intent Filter in the **application B** to handle the **application A** call?

Comment: Could you post your `TestActivity` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me (just add `category`):

```
<activity android:name=".TestActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="testapp" /> // <data android:scheme="testapp" android:host="details"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```